# 'Call to a member function paginate() on array' Error occurred for multiple join tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5.1, laravel-query-builder, laravel-paginate

Laravel query builder needs to paginate from multiple join tables.

I've tried many ways to paginate this query. But nothing.

**Controller.php**

```
$ord_heds = DB::select('select d.family, d.category, d.product_img, d.ord_ref, m.min_qty, m.max_qty, t.qty, t.value, SUM(replace(d.value,",","")) as ordval, SUM(replace(d.qty,",","")) as Tord_qty, COUNT(d.qty) as no_of_items_ordered, (select COUNT(itemCode) as mcount from item_statuses where '.'s'.$siteG.' ="'.$site.'" and itemCode in (select itemCode FROM items WHERE category=d.category and brand=d.family)) as manCount, (select COUNT(itemCode) as mcount1 from item_statuses where '.'s'.$siteG.' ="'.$site.'" and itemCode in (select itemCode FROM items WHERE category=d.category and brand=d.family and itemCode in (select itemcode FROM ord_dets where ord_dets.site = "'.$ordSite.'"))) as ordManCount FROM ord_dets d JOIN ord__heds h ON d.ord_ref = h.id INNER JOIN min__maxes m ON d.category = m.category AND d.site = m.site AND d.scode = m.season INNER JOIN targets t ON d.category = t.category AND d.family = t.brand AND d.month = t.month AND d.year = t.year AND d.site = t.site WHERE h.month = "'.$date[1].'" AND h.year = "'.$date[0].'" AND h.site = "'.$ordSite.'" GROUP BY d.family, d.category, d.product_img, d.ord_ref, m.min_qty, m.max_qty, t.qty, t.value');

$pag = $ord_heds->paginate(10);

dd($pag);
```

Above code result an error 'FatalThrowableError Call to a member function paginate() on array'.

Comment: Debug `$ord_heds` first. 
If it returns an array, you are getting a result, while `paginate` can be used with a DB query object NOT a result.
Check your query and try to use query builder properly.

Comment: Thnakz @ Shudhansh Shekhar my result is this, array:16 [▼
  0 => {#342 ▶}
  1 => {#348 ▶}
  2 => {#350 ▶}
  3 => {#341 ▶}
  4 => {#353 ▶}
  5 => {#349 ▶}
  6 => {#355 ▶}
  7 => {#356 ▶}
  8 => {#357 ▶}
  9 => {#358 ▶}
  10 => {#359 ▶}
  11 => {#360 ▶}
  12 => {#361 ▶}
  13 => {#362 ▶}
  14 => {#363 ▶}
  15 => {#364 ▶}
], then how can I return this as a DB query object

Comment: It is probably a good idea to line-wrap that query **in your code file**, and then reflect that same change here. It is not very readable on one line, and that will make understanding it hard for you, and reading it hard for readers.

Comment: As from the Laravel definition for your raw queries,  
" The select method will always return an array of results. Each result within the array will be a PHP stdClass object, allowing you to access the values of the result. "
So, you just can't paginate by using the queries that you have tried.

Comment: Your code is too clumsy. You better change your queries in more query builder way rather than just using raw query. 
Also try to get query object.
For example: For getting query i'll use `DB::table()->where()`. For getting first result i'll use  `DB::table()->where()->first()`